# Amount of antimatter needed to propel large spacecraft?

Tags: physics, hard-science, space-travel, spaceships, propulsion

Okay, So i'm not really into physics or mathematics but i'm trying my best to learn some bit of how the calculations needed for the amount of antimatter needed to propel a spacecrafft to relativistic speeds.

So lets take a realistic spacecraft like the ISV Venture Star from Avatar.
[image]

So, according to the wiki, The ISV class of ships is accelerated to ***0.7c for 6 to 7 months*** straight from Earth to Alpha-Centauri and vice versa.

It carries approximately ***250 metric tons*** of cargo at full capacity which included all 250 passengers, two valkyrie shuttles and the cargo racks loaded.

Let's recalculate the amount of antimatter required for a longer duration of constant acceleration, specifically 6.5 months, which is approximately 4,745 hours:

**1. Spacecraft Mass:** Assume a spacecraft mass (including cargo,
colonists, shuttles, and structure) of 250 metric tons, which is
approximately 250,000 kilograms.

**2. Desired Acceleration:**  Let's assume the spacecraft accelerates at a constant rate for a 6.5 Months (4,745 Hours). The desired final velocity is 0.7c (70% of the speed of light).

**3. Relativistic Effects:** When approaching the speed of light, relativistic effects become significant. To account for this, we'll use the relativistic rocket equation:

Δv = c * tanh⁻¹(a * Δt / c)

Where:

- Δv is the change in velocity (0.7c - 0c = 0.7c).
- a is the constant acceleration.
- Δt is the time duration in the spaceship's frame (4,745 hours).

**4. Antimatter Propulsion Efficiency:** We'll assume 100% conversion efficiency of antimatter to energy (which is an idealized assumption and may not be achievable in practice).

Now, we can solve for the required acceleration (a):

**Now, we calculate the required energy (E) to achieve this acceleration:**

E = (1/2) * m * Δv²

Where m is the spacecraft mass and Δv is the change in velocity.

E ≈ (1/2) * 250,000 kg * (0.7c)²

Next, we convert the energy to antimatter mass using Einstein's mass-energy equivalence (E = mc²):

m = E / c²

Plugging in the values:

m ≈ [(1/2) * 250,000 kg * (0.7c)²] / c²

**m ≈ 0.000214 kilograms of antimatter**

So, approximately 0.000214 kilograms (or 0.214 grams) of antimatter would be required to propel the spacecraft to 0.7 times the speed of light (0.7c) over a duration of 6.5 months with the corrected assumptions.

Is my math correct in this?

And if that's the case... THAT'S ALL THE AMOUNT OF ANTIMATTER NEEDED to propel such a big ass ship??? not even 1 kg? Is this how powerful antimatter is?

I mean of course producing it is the riskiest economic suicide ever but I never thought antimatter would be absolutely this intense.

Edit: I made a mistake. I literally calculated 0.7 the decimal as opposed to 0.7 light speed (209854720.6) and only used c as opposed to c². its indeed 61,250 kgs of antimatter for the 250,000.

Comment: You need to move the decimal place, then it all makes sense

Comment: Typing your exact equation [into WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5B%281%2F2%29+*+250%2C000+kg+*+%280.7c%29%C2%B2%5D+%2F+c%C2%B2) gives 61,000 kg. I'm not sure what happened here, but this updated result is consistent with stuff I've heard about relativistic antimatter starships being, in large part, fuel mass (remember, you also need a bunch more to slow down, and that counts as the mass you're accelerating...). See [Frisbee](https://web.archive.org/web/20060601234257/http://www.aiaa.org/Participate/Uploads/2003-4676.pdf) as an example.

Comment: I got 61.25 tons of matter *plus* antimatter... you need to halve the amount since antimatter is annihilated with an equivalent amount of matter.

Comment: Your efficiency has to be 100%. If it's just 99.99%, the 0.01% waste heat will melt the ship.

Comment: You absolutely _cannot_ use the classical kinetic energy equation when you're dealing with significant fractions of the speed of light. You must use the relativistic kinetic energy equation if you hope to be accurate.

Comment: "250 metric tons, which is approximately 250,000 kilograms"

Comment: Ashimix a really fundamental mistake you're making.  "antimatter" **just generates energy**.  Let's say for simplicity, it generates electricity. Electricity won't get you anywhere.  **You need propellant.**

Comment: @Fattie But the matter/anti-matter reaction will produce a wide range of particles, probably mostly high-energy photons. Make sure that those are all going in the same direction, and that’s your propellant. How to achieve that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: M.Scott - indeed (I guess you need a REALLY GOOD mirror right! :) ); I meant to be clearer I was pointing out to the OP the propellant approach!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can mark a answer to be correct if it uses classical mechanics, but whatever. $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ definitely does not work at these speeds anymore, plus there is a factor missing.

First of all, the ISV´s from Avatar are not realistic. These antimatter engines would be screamingly radioactive, and the crew/cargo section is right in the middle of the two jets. Leaving aside the radiant heat from this, the radiation should kill everything and transmutate all structures into lead. Also, the exhaust wouldn't be blue. In fact, it would be invisible from most angles due to Doppler effects.

Anyways, both you and the Monty guy used way to much abstraction. What you are trying to do is answer a question about *energy*. To kind of show the thought process, we know the ship has to presumably slow down, and we can assume the deceleration phase is symetric to the acceleration phase. The total energy is just:

$E_{total} = 2E_{\Delta V}$

Ehere $E_{\Delta V}$ is the energy needed to change the velocity for the acceleration / deceleration phase.

Leaving aside abstraction, we know $E_{\Delta V}$ is a quantity of kinetic energy, so $E_{\Delta V}$ has to follow some;

$E_{\Delta V} = m_0c^2 \left( \frac{1}{\gamma}-1 \right)$ where $\gamma = \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$

This is in essence the kinetic energy, the amount of Work, the ship / propulsion system has to do. If we plug in your numbers, we get something like;

$E_{\Delta V} = 250000000kg \times 299792458\frac{m}{s}^2 \times \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{(0.7 \times 299792458\frac{m}{s})^2}{299792458\frac{m}{s}^2}}} -1\right)$

$E_{\Delta V} = 9\times10^{24}$

Then of course:

$E_{total} = 2E_{\Delta V}$

$E_{total} = 2 \times 9\times10^{24}$

$E_{total} = 1.8\times10^{25}$

That is a lot of energy.

To figure out how much antimatter we need, we can once again drop abstraction and just use *the* equation. As $E = mc^2$ tells us, energy and mass are truly the same quantity. Since antimatter annihilation, theoretically, converts 100% of mass to energy, this is one of these times where $E = mc^2$ can be used. We know what $E$ is, we know the speed of light.

$E = mc^2$

$\frac{E}{c^2} = m$

$\frac{1.8\times10^{25}}{299792458\frac{m}{s}^2} = 200140042 kg$

$m \approx 200000 t$

Well that's a downer, but actually not that surprising. 0.7c is very fast, and at this point the kinetic energy is well into its exponential phase. Plus you need to slow down again. How long this burn lasts, by the way, is really irrelevant. To illustrate the point, if we lower the desired speed to 0.5c, we get;

$\dot{m} = 77350 t$

Antimatter works best at medium relativistic speeds. You won't get to 70% with it, well if you don't plan on 70% of your ship being antimatter.

That being said, these calculations are very wrong / idealized as a physicist might say. Annihilation is neither 100% effective, nor can be converted into a change in momentum. Indeed, annihilation produces omnidirectional radiation, most of it in the form of gamma rays and a lot of heat. You would be lucky to covert 50% of the annihilation energy into thrust. The rest will just be heat, so slap a $\frac{2}{1}$ factor on all of these. Alternatively, heating up a propellant using annihilation might yield  70% efficiency, but now you have to carry a propellant with you.

Really, to get to these speeds all you can really do is use power beaming and staging of some sort.

EDIT; I just saw you said 250 tons for the entire spacecraft.  In that case:

$m \approx 200 t$

$\dot{m} = 77.3 t$

Its just linear from the perspective of the ship but no need to get into that. The math is the same, just $m_0$ changes.

EDIT #2; As quarague pointed out, this math has a flaw in that it sort of assumes the mass of the propellant is 0. Meaning the start and end mass of the ship is constant. So ill include some more stuff to give a more accurate answer;

In essence, we will be using the equation;

$\frac{M}{m} = \gamma(1+\frac{v}{c})-1 $

Note, $\frac{M}{m}$ is the mass fraction, we are interested in $M$ as $m$ is our payload / vessel mass. Solving for $M$ we get;

$M = e^{\frac{aT}{c}}-1$

Which again is a sort of proportionality constant, if $M$ is 2, that means for ever 1kg of $m$ we need 2kg of $M$ or fuel. You might notice a conspicuous $T$ in there. This is the burn time, or how long we plan to accelerate. You might also notice that the $aT$ term is just some $\frac{x}{c}$ and we actually simplify further to;

$M = e^{\frac{v}{c}}-1$

This is more illustrative since our result is independent of acceleration and Time, which conceptually makes sense. While in reality a less powerful engine will almost always be more efficient (see Ion Drives) we dont really care for that. Finally, we need to consider that we want to slow down again, which works out to;

$M = e^{\frac{2v}{c}}-1$

Using this, for $v = 0.7c$ we get $M = 3.055$. Again this is not actually true because we are basically doing the $E = mc^2$ math from above while taking acceleration into account. But this is all still 100% efficient. But this tells us that a Ship, using Antimatter, would have to have 3 times as much fuel as mass to reach 70% the speed of light and slow down again.

Comment: While a totally awesome answer, I believe the OP is really missing the completely fundamental point that space ships work with propellant.

Comment: Ahh yes. thank you. The reason I marked it answered cause I didn't expect this.
I got some of the maths to show and that's it for me as my world doesn't focus a lot on the deep math stuff.

But you are right though that the ISV class ships are not realistic in the sense that they are not long enough. If I recall, The actual original design for the ship is actually 4KM long. Which I suspected is for the dissipation of the gamma rays the engines will fart out.

James Cameron just pulled an the "unobtanium" trope to wish all the complexity away so theres that:)

Comment: @Fattie , thanks. Apparently, once you do all the math, Antimatter annihilation + Propellant is better than pure Antimatter propulsion. So you get away with less total mass for the same dV. No idea how that works, but its probably fine. As for OP, their math isnt to far off. But it misses a bunch of things, like the fact you need twice the energy for the slowing down part, i also dont get why the included a time measurement

Comment: EH - good one ...

Comment: @Ashimix that is the right move. I tried to make fast interstellar travel work, it just dosnt xD You have to add some magic bean in there somewhere. Otherwise its a non starter for all practical purposes. As for the ISV length, its really the whole geometry i take issue with. Like, the way the cargo part just dangles below the engine is an inherently unstable configuration. The gamma rays you can deal with, but like not when you are in-between two continuous gamma ray bursts xD

Comment: Ashimix ... you may be (wildly) underestimating the un-realistic-ness of the ships.  *"original design for the ship is actually 4KM long..."*  It's likely that if we magically said "Oh, they are 10,000 km long" it wouldn't help matters.  note that just to begin with, even with "ultimate handwaving" it would be INCREDIBLY hard to hold, contain, bottle *the odd spoonful* of anitmatter - far less "1000s of tons" of antimatter

Comment: @ErikHall If I recall, The tractor-configuraiton idea liek this was actually originally from Charles Pellegrino. In which in his design, His ship is 10km long with engines on both the front and back. In terms of the "gamma ray fart death"... You have to remember that the ships engines are actually angled by 3 degrees so that the plume forms a V shape to go atleast angle it away. Do you think that that helps by a bit?

Comment: @Ashimix ToughSF made a post about the OG design which is much more sensible. As for the 3 degrees angle. That helps precisely 0 bit. All this does is make the thrust efficiency lower. These engines are particle accelerators which spew out quadrillions of charged particles per second, the magnetic fields, pressure gradients etc will make sure everything in a wide cone underneath the nozzle gets eradiated.

Comment: @ErikHall Thanks. During the first Avatar, I was actually vibing the venture star class of ships. The 1.6 km length, I can deal with it. But take a look at avatar 2 where they LITERALLY tuened the ISV into the ships from Independence day and for some reason everybody just went out of their pods with the plume still in orbit and destroying the entire miles of ecosystem surrouonding them. It's when I lost it. So does this mean... That a tractor coniguration is not the best for someting like this?

Comment: @Ashimix i have a lot to say about the landing sequence from Avatar 2, but these comment sections are not for prolonged discussions. I think there is some way to move it into a chat. For now, all i will say is that these ships couldnt land on a planet this way, for a wide range of reasons. As for the tractor config, well for a Skycrane type maneuver it is ok. But the Engines are the problem. They produce the energy of two continous 100Mt nuclear detonations each second.

Comment: @ErikHall, the clever thing about the length is that it lets you greatly reduce the shielding.  Instead of needing thick shielding on the leading edge of the crew section, you put a narrow block of thick shielding far up the cable, and it casts a radiation shadow on the crew section.

Comment: @Mark that is a valid idea, which is invalidated when the exhaust jet passes right along the crew section. That length is doing nothing

Comment: Would you consider adding units to the answer where they are missing? It's really important for the context of some of the results. Like, $1.8\times10^{25}\ \mathrm{J}$ is a huge amount of energy but $1.8\times10^{25}\ \mathrm{eV}$ is not so much. (I mean, still a lot on human scales, but rather little for a spaceship.) $1.8\times10^{25}$ radio-frequency photons' worth of energy is even less.

Comment: `Antimatter annihilation + Propellant is better than pure Antimatter propulsion.` Barring inefficient engine designs, adding more propellant to your antimatter engine's exhaust steam will *not* increase your dv. It will lower your exhaust velocity which requires a very substantial increase in ship mass to compensate.

Comment: @BMF well its really not that easy. Antimatter + propellant is better because you get to keep more of the energy produced by annihilation. The wiki article agrees with me here.

Comment: Your computation still misses an important aspect, namely that you need to accelerate the fuel as well. You computed 200t of antimatter to accelerate 250t of cargo but that means at the beginning you need to accelerate 450t of total mass so these 200t won't get you quite to the speed you want. This kind of computation is usually done via the 'rocket equation'

Comment: @quarague It does. The math considers the total kinetic energy the vessel has. Which by definition includes the energy you spend during acceleration.

Comment: It doesn't. You compute the energy needed to accelerate 250t and then compute how many tons of antimatter that would correspond to. That is not enough. The mass of the space ship is fuel + cargo and is not constant over time. The rocket equation is a differential equation and people usually use some calculator for solving that (easy to find with google).

Comment: @quarague god damit, yeah sorry i misread your initial comment. You are right, the mass should be higher.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. 250 tons of *cargo*, *not* 250 tons of *ship*.  I'd be more inclined to believe *1000* tons of ship including cargo.
2. Somehow, your calculations were wrong... I got 61,250 kg of matter from your m ≈ [(1/2) * 250,000 kg * (0.7c)²] / c² formula, meaning that you'd need 30.625 *tons* of antimatter.

However, since I believe that you have the mass wrong:

m ≈ [(1/2) * 1,000,000 kg * (0.7c)²] / c² ≈ 245,000 kg

Since the 245t is both matter and antimatter, you'd need about 122.5 tons of antimatter.  That's an *awful* lot of antimatter... and that's just to accelerate the ship.

Since we'd have to *de*celerate the ship at the other end of the trip, we could easily assume an equal amount of antimatteer again.

So, you *would* likely need the full 245 tons of antimatter.

Of course, as you used the antimatter, your ship would get lighter, and need less energy to accelerate, but I'd err on the side of having the extra fuel, just in case of emergencies or miscalculations.

I'm assuming C=300,000,000 m/s, which is a little pessimistic.  This also doesn't take relativistic effects into consideration.

Comment: Holy shit. I made a mistake. I literally calculated 0.7 the decimal as opposed to 0.7 light speed (209854720.6) and only used c as opposed to c².

its indeed 61,250 kgs of antimatte for the 250,000.

Question though. when it says 61k kg of antimatter. is it literally 61,000 kgs of antihydrogen? Thats how much the antimatter propellant capsule woudl weight if it was on earth???

Comment: @Ashimix That's 61250kg of *total reactants*.  That would include both matter and antimatter to annihilate it with... and as I said, that's just for the acceleration leg, before relativistic effects.  But basically, yes, that's how much it would weigh... *not including containment*.  All things considered, 1000t may also be too light...

Comment: One of the unfortunate problems with trying to stick to real physics as we understand it today to deal with future tech is that 245 tons of antimatter makes the ship pretty easy to destroy. Just puncture the tanks. Foof!

Comment: @JBH I can't imagine why they'd need FOOF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioxygen_difluoride)... surely the antimatter would be better... and worse.

Comment: Since you're working with non-trivial fuel fractions, you can't just double the fuel requirements to account for deceleration, you need to use the full [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation), or the relativistic variant if you're flying in a relativistic universe.

Comment: @MontyWild I perceive this solution as having the same problem as a space ship with energy weapons powerful enough to actually matter in combat. In the latter case, the ship must either generate substantially more instantanous power than it ever needs in non-combat situations, meaning wasted fuel and huge heat sinks to dissipate the energy when not needed (can you turn off an antimatter generator?), or a battery so large that if your enemy hits it you explode brilliantly (foof!). That much antimatter feels like a similar problem. Puncture the tank. Foof!

Comment: @MontyWild +1, BTW, for the chemistry joke. Heaven help us if anybody is using FOOF.